# Where can I find a decent Seal Script font?

Tags: seal

I have 9 TrueType fonts that include seal script hanzi, but do not include them entirely. Could someone show me a decent font, or send me via email the shuowen jiezi font?

Comment: Some of them need to be paid for personal use, http://www.zhaozi.cn/e/search/result/?searchid=309324

Answer (score 5):

http://web.hku.hk/~jwilam/chinese/font.htm

There's two:

- bnucdp.ttf
- ebas927.ttf (link broken; try https://www.moedict.tw/fonts/truetype/cns11643/)

Note that 說文 records many variants, so the default one that appears when you type Chinese may not be the "orthodox variant" that you're looking for (I know from experience because I've used these fonts before). If you're good at reading seal script, you should open the font with a character map to get the unicode directly to type the variant you want.

Also, many characters that we use today may not have existed as a seal script character. They may have used another character for the same word, or the word just didn't exist back then. You can't do anything in this case except construct your own seal script character for those.

These problems I've mentioned might be the same problem you're having with your existing set of 9 fonts, and you may have these two fonts already.

Comment: the link to ebase927.ttf doesn't work :( any mac os friendly fonts available?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 Try https://www.moedict.tw/fonts/truetype/cns11643/ instead. I don't know of anything that's specifically macOS, sorry. You should ask OP, who said they have a collection of 9 fonts.

Comment: many many thanks :) the web pages provided mentioned downloading an *.exe file, which is windows only. anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I will try to upload the package with the 9 fonts to mediafire... As soon as i do it i will post the link here.

Comment: Here it goes: http://www.mediafire.com/file/gv63qz6g4c8oct8/Jinwen%20Dazhuan%20Lishu%20fonts.rar
it includes 15 fonts, with the ebas927.ttf

Answer (score 2):

Here's one for the small seal script I found by searching 白舟小篆

https://www.fonts.net.cn/font-34546210551.html

Does it have better coverage for what you're working on? It has the best coverage of the fonts I've been looking through for the small seal script.

Some other search terms that look promising on that site:

白舟 (Hakasyu/Hakashu who makes that font I listed above. Their website is: http://www.hakusyu.com/index.php)

小篆 (small seal script)

秦篆 (another name for small seal script)

篆書 (seal script)

大篆 (large seal)

甲骨文 (oracle bone script)

龜甲獸骨文字 (longer name for oracle bone script)

These don't provide much as search results on that font site but they might be useful terms for people who find themselves here:

九畳 (nine fold)

鳥書 (bird script)

鳥篆 (bird seal script)

蟲書 (worm script)

Comment: By the way, 大篆 is not a script style - it's what calligraphers would call pre-Qin writing.